# problem display tile when config tilecache for WMS

Tags: qgis, mapserver, tilecache

i have a problem with config tilecache for WMS
when i have shown it. but there are proplem when display tiles.

[image]

any idea?

this is my config for tilecache.cfg

```
[world]
```

type=WMS
url=myserver/mapserv.exe?mode=map&map=C:\Mapffiles\countries.main.map
layers=countries
bbox=-180, -90, 180, 90
srs=EPSG:4326
extension=png
reproject=true
levels=15
size=256,256
metaSize=5,5 
sendfile=yes 
metaTile=true

when i display it in QGIS then it fails as above

Comment: please show us the code you are using to make the map

Answer (score 2):

This problem ususally happens when you enter the URL of a tile instead of the URL of the service when configuring your WMS layer. Like iant said, please provide us with more information if you want help.

Note that when you specify your `WMS URL`, you must not specify the `/0/0/0.png` at the end.